# python code to write extracted info to text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, file-writing

I just wrote a simple python program to extract links from Google News which was successful.

The issue I'm having now is I want to write or append all those links to a text file but it only writes the first link and not all the links. How do I achieve this?

My code is shown below:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def scrape(self):
        req = urlopen(self.site)
        html = req.read()
        parser = "html.parser"
        sp = Soup(html, parser)
        news_list = sp.find_all("a")
        for tag in news_list:
            url = tag.get("href")
            print("\n", url)
            print("-" * 110)
            with open("elder.txt", "w+") as f:
                f.write(str(url))

news = "https://news.google.com"
Scraper(news).scrape()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you don't have the file open throughout. You open it once for every iteration in the for loop.

Keep it open throughout the function and it would work.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site
    def scrape(self):
        with open("elder.txt", "w+") as f:
            req = urlopen(self.site)
            html = req.read()
            parser = "html.parser"
            sp = Soup(html, parser)
            news_list = sp.find_all("a")
            for tag in news_list:
                url = tag.get("href")
                print("\n", url)
                print("-" * 110)
                f.write(str(url) + '\n')

news = "https://news.google.com"
links = Scraper(news).scrape()
```

Try this.

Comment: this actually worked, sorry for not replying over 2 years ago.

Comment: Haha no worries, have an awesome day! @OlowuAbayomi

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that you open a file inside the loop. What it means?, when you open file with "w+" mode it'll delete previous data of the file (Just rewrite it). By the way, you're using the wrong mode, "w+" is used for writing and reading (both). You need to use "w" mode (only writing) and put it before the loop, because we want to use the same file for all the loop process and write to the same location as you understood.

The code you need:

```
def scrape(self):
    req = urlopen(self.site)
    html = req.read()
    parser = "html.parser"
    sp = Soup(html, parser)
    news_list = sp.find_all("a")
    with open("elder.txt", "w") as f:
        for tag in news_list:
            url = tag.get("href")
            print("\n", url)
            print("-" * 110)

            f.write(str(url))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file earlier, rather than opening it just before each url is written.

What you have currently just opens the file a-new, clearing it out before you write.

```
with open("elder.txt", "w+") as f:
    for tag in news_list:
        url = tag.get("href")
        print("\n", url)
        print("-" * 110)
        f.write(str(url))
```

or use: `open("elder.txt", "a")` to append to the file each time you run your script.